# Deserializing wsdl object doesn't include all the objects c#

Tags: c#, web-services, serialization, wsdl

I have a wsdl that I used to create a web reference(generates reference.cs) and i am able to create the objects i want and correctly deserialize which i am sending to a web service. The issue i am having is that the client wants the deserialized xml to include all the objects in the outgoing xml that are not created. For example lets say i have object a,b,c and i create object a and b and set values for them when i deserialize object c is not included. This is only a problem because there are 100's of objects that need to be included that are not having values set. Currently the work around is to create all the objects that are not being used as well which is extremely time consuming. If anyone has ran into a similar situation and advice would be much appreciated.

```
    <root>
      <a>value</a>
      <b>value</b>
    </root>
```

If i don't create object c it is not included in deserialization.

desired output:

```
    <root>
      <a>value</a>
      <b>value</b>
      </c>
    </root>
```

I am using the XmlSerializer object to perform deserialization and also using .NET 4.5.1

Comment: Hi, It depends on your class structure, could you please post your C class

Comment: Are you talking about reference.cs or class that is doing the deserialization?

Comment: reference.cs i mean sorry

Comment: It's way to big to post whole thing. Is there a particular part that would be what you need to see?

Comment: i would like to know if you are the objects owner (developer) so why are you talking about Serialize ? or xml file receiver ? do you want to generate a xml file and send it to your client involving classes with no value set ? thk

Comment: I am talking about serialize because i create the object from reference.cs then i serialize and send the xml to the client. Yes i am the developer. The client provided wsdl and i created reference.cs from wsdl.